# Are there words that specify that a number was pronounced 'six double zero ' vs 'six zero zero'?

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

Are there words that specify that a number, say 600 was or is to be pronounced 'six double zero ' vs 'six zero zero'?

How about six double oh vs six oh oh? Would that be the same word?
How about when you are spelling something, e.g. 'double el' rather than 'el el' for 'll'.
Also, should you say 'capital double el' or 'double capital el' for 'LL'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I say whether or not a number was pronounced like a telephone number or zip code. Are there words for this?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/564093/how-do-i-say-whether-or-not-a-number-was-pronounced-like-a-telephone-number-or-z)

Comment: I once heard someone trying to obtain a caller's phone number. "Three five eight nine? But [local] phone numbers have five digits, and that is only four." The number turned out to be 55589.

Comment: Why combine different questions into one post?

Comment: @Joachim No, it doesn't.